# UISearchDisplayController is not displaying any cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UISearchDisplayController that is properly hooked up in Interface Builder.

```
delegate = Files Owner
searchBar = Search Bar
searchContentsController = Files Owner
searchResultsDataSource = Files Owner
searchResultsDelegate = Files Owner
```

When my UITableView calls `numberoOfRowsInSection:` the correct number is returned.

However, my cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` don't even reach:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 if (tblView == searchController.searchResultsTableView){
  NSLog(@"search will go here");
  UITableViewCell* cell = [self provideSearchQueryCells:tblView identifer:@"searchQueryCell"];
  STSymbol *aSymbol = [self.searchQueryResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  cell.textLabel.text = aSymbol.symbol;
  cell.detailTextLabel.text = aSymbol.symbol_title;

  return cell;
 }
 else { ... }
```

It always goes to the else condition.

I am not exactly sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to create an instance of a UISearchDisplayController instead of using self.searchDisplayController.

Answer (score 1):

use the following. It should work.

```
 if ([tblView isEqual:[searchController searchResultsTableView]]) {
...
}
```

you should also make sure the search result row count is correct as in :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if ([tblView isEqual:[searchController searchResultsTableView]]) {
        return [self.searchResults count];
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess from this close in on the code, but are we looking at the search display controller itself? Maybe your `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView` should just be `self.searchResultsTableView`.

I can't be sure without knowing your delegates.

Comment: I believe so, because this code is in a UITableViewController subclass. self.searchResultsTableView is not a property in a UITableViewController.

Comment: I have modified my post, to show how the delegates are wired up in IB.